# Height and width are not scaling while using SVG <use> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to achieve an opacity slider of width:250 and height:32, but the width and height are not scaling.I can achieve this easily in innerSVG, but as I might be using it in many places, with varied width, height and fill color as well, I need to do this using  tag. Can you help me out? This is my code:

```
 <svg style='width:0px;height:0px'>
          <defs>
            <mask id='zcolorslider-mask'>
              <linearGradient id=zcolorslider-maskgrad x1='0' y1='0' x2='1' y2='0'>
                <stop offset='0' stop-color='#000000'> </stop>
                <stop offset='1' stop-color='#ffffff'> </stop>
              </linearGradient>
              <rect width=32 height=32 fill='url(#zcolorslider-maskgrad)'></rect>
            </mask>
          </defs>
          <g id='zcolorslider-opacitybar'>
            <rect width=32 height=32 fill=blue mask=url(#zcolorslider-mask)></rect>
          </g>
        </svg>

        <div class='colorslider'>
          <svg width=100% height=100% fill=pink viewBox='0 0 32 32'>
            <use width=100% height=100% xlink:href='#zcolorslider-opacitybar' />
          </svg>
        </div>
```

Working url : [colorslider](https://jsfiddle.net/2e8nqsdz/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your `.colorslider` like this:

```
    <div class='colorslider'>
      <svg width="100%" height="100%"
           viewBox="0 0 32 32" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <use xlink:href='#zcolorslider-opacitybar' />
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Take care to write valid html - use quotes around attribute values.

[`preserveAspectRatio`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) governs the way your grafic is rendered inside the viewport. It has a default value of `"xMidYMid meet"`, which means that the largest grafic that fits into the viewport without distorting the widht/height ratio is painted into the middle. You have to override it to scale your image unevenly.

Comment: Working fine.. Thank you